# Can I use a UISearchController to select an API parameter (and then populate cells accordingly), rather than filtering existing cells?

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

For example,

Lets say I have an array of countries. ["France","Germany","Spain]

This country is a parameter to the API I am using. The API only requires one country

What I am trying to achieve is, when a user taps on the search box, it then presents all countries within the array ["France","Germany","Spain]

The user taps on, and therefore selects, one country ["Germany"]

When they do this, there is then an API call, using "Germany" as the parameter. All dynamic table view cells are then populated with the JSON data using "Germany" as a parameter

Therefore, rather than the search box filtering existing results, it used as a means of selected the parameter (country) for the API call

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Its possible it just depends on how your API is designed.  If your API has a .GET call to provide all available countries you can call that first to populate those results in your search results.

Comment: Thanks, I was planning on storing the countries in a local array since they won't change and it will reduce the number of API calls. Or is this bad practice?

Comment: what would happen if a user starts typing in the search box? would still filter as expected?

Comment: If a user types in a search box, it should filter the list of countries. I.e typing "Ge" shows Germany only (which can then be selected by tapping). Once selected, it goes into the API, and shows the Germany JSON data in tableview cells